# ASN1. Sequence vs Set

Tags: certificate, rsa, x509, asn.1

I'm implementing an ASN1 parser to decode x509 certificates. There are sequence and set tags that you can use. I don't see a reason why those two shouldn't be the same thing.

What is the difference, and appropriate time to use each?

Answer (score 4):

A sequence is ordered, a set is not.

When would a set be appropriate? One example might be when encoding huge chunks of data, where bringing them in the right order at the sender would cause more work than mandating that they be accepted in any order.

Answer (score 3):

*As an addendum to @ChristophSommer's answer*

> A sequence is ordered, a set is not.

... and this makes a difference e.g. when encoding some object. Using DER (distinguished encoding rules) requires a distinguished order of set elements while sequence elements keep their original order.

> appropriate time to use each

As Christoph's answer indicates, you use a sequence for entries for which the order of appearance in the sequence is relevant, and a set for entries for which the order is irrelevant.

Furthermore the entries of a set usually are assumed to be unique, no two identical entries in a set, while a sequence may contain many identical entries.

Comment: "usually are assumed to beunique " -- Are duplicate set entries *allowed* in DER? How is uniqueness for constructed types defined?

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude "Are duplicate set entries *allowed* in DER?" - That's a good question. Originally I'd have said "No" but looking at ITU-T Rec. X.680 and ITU-T Rec. X.690 I only see formulations for sets along the lines of "an unordered list of zero, one or more values of the component type"; this would allow for duplicates... I'm surprised.

Comment: You mention (correctly) that DER, being unambiguous, specifies a `distinguished order of set elements` -- *how* are they sorted / what is this ordering? That may be a clue or a thread that'd be productive to pull on, since any unambiguous sorting order will have corner-cases around identical items that will, even if not discussed in the spec, at least yield interesting results to check out implementations of due to the unyielding nature of computer code.

Comment: "The encodings of the component values of a set-of value shall appear in ascending order, the encodings being compared
as octet strings with the shorter components being padded at their trailing end with 0-octets." - I miss a "strict" in the order definition; requiring a strictly ascending order would forbid duplicates...